# Run-time error '1004' in a column to row transposition

Tags: vba, excel

On the first 'For' loop line of the second chunk:

I get

> Run-time error '1004'

Because this part of the code is at the end of the whole code, I moved the Dimensions and object Sets prior to the problematic lines.

I have the same 'For' loop higher in the code in **Chunk 1** below.
The only difference is that in **Chunk 2** the 'For'loop is for 'í' and in **Chunk 2** is for 'k'.

**Chunk 1:**

```
Dim ExposureDataInput As Worksheet
Dim ManualSimulation As Worksheet
    
Set EDI = Sheets("ExposureDataInput")
Set MS = Sheets("ManualSimulation")
    
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim j As Integer
            
For i = 2 To EDI.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                
    If EDI.Range("B" & i).Value > 0 Then
                    
        n = MS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MS.Range("A" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 1).Value
                        
        n = MS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MS.Range("B" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 2).Value
                            
        n = MS.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MS.Range("C" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 4).Value
                                
        n = MS.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MS.Range("D" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 6).Value
                        
        n = MS.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MS.Range("E" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 8).Value
                        
        n = MS.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MS.Range("F" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 10).Value
                        
        n = MS.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MS.Range("G" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 12).Value
                        
    End If
                
Next i
```

**Chunk 2:**

> error 424: Object Required or error 1004: Dimension Not Set.

Same Dimensions are set for 'í', 'n' & 'j' in **Chunk 1**.

```
Dim HistoricalDataandExcessReturns As Worksheet

Set HDaER = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns")

Dim k As Integer
Dim y As Integer
                    
For k = 2 To EDI.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        
    If EDI.Range("B" & k).Value > 0 Then
                            
        y = HDaER.Range(Columns.Count & 1).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        HDaER.Range(y & 1).Value = EDI.Cells(1, k).Value
            
        y = HDaER.Range(Columns.Count & 2).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        HDaER.Range(y & 2).Value = EDI.Cells(2, k).Value 
           
    End If
                            
Next k
```

**Chunk 3** with similar `For` loop:

```
For j = 2 To MS.Range("$A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        
    With MS.Range("$J" & j).Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinous
        .Color = vbWhite
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
                            
    With MS.Range("$K" & j).Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinous
        .Color = vbWhite
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
                            
    With MS.Range("$L" & j).Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinous
        .Color = vbWhite
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
                     
Next j
```

Generally I would prefer a direct link between the cells in 'MS' ws and the cells in the 'HDaER' ws row that I want to transpose to. I like the '=' approach.

I replaced 'MS' sheet with 'EDI' sheet in **Chunk 1** to make it almost identical with the `Rows.Count` for 'i' in **Chunk 2**.

How can I tweak the 'For' loop to work with the '='?

Comment: Hm there are 4 lines there...

Comment: Noted. Meant just the firs one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Range like that (it's column then row), use Cells instead. Plus it's `xltoleft`.

```
'For k = 2 To MS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'    y = HDaER.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xltoLeft).Column + 1
'    HDaER.Cells(1, y).Value = MS.Cells(k, 1).Value
'Next k

'Avoiding a loop, think this will work
'ms.Range("A2", ms.Range("A" & ms.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
'HDaER.Cells(1, HDaER.Columns.Count).End(xltoLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Sub x()

Dim HDaER As Worksheet, MS As Worksheet

Set HDaER = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns")
Set MS =  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ManualSimulation")

MS.Range("A2", MS.Range("A" & MS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
HDaER.Cells(1, HDaER.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: My pleasure. Perhaps you could get in the habit of accepting answers to your questions

Comment: However,

'Run-time error '424':

Object Required

On the first line.

:(

Comment: On which line? Have you declared and defined `MS` and `HDaER` as worksheets?

Comment: Yes. In the first line there is nothing I haven't used higher up in the code. Works fine in previous lines...

Comment: You need to be precise - what do you mean by the first line? I don't know if you are using the loop or the copy/paste.

Comment: If you are using the former, can you try the latter?

Comment: I've made a small change to the code, but not sure it will make a difference. If it doesn't I think you'll have to post the rest of your code as this works for me.

Comment: Sorry, not sure it does. Let's try to nail down the specific problem you had with my code. Can you try the short procedure I have added above (x) and let me know how you get on.

Comment: @SLR Yes, this works fine now. 
I guess I will have to go with this.

Pls take one more look at the loop. 
What happens now is that it piles up all the cells from MS ws in A1 in HDaER...
I updated the code. See below.


 'For k = 2 To EDI.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If EDI.Range("A" & k) > 0 Then            
            l = HDaER.Range("A1" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            HDaER.Range("A1" & l).Value = EDI.Cells(1, k).Value
        End If
    Next k'


Thanks a million.

Comment: OK. You need `l = HDaER.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1` as Range is column then row. and difficult to use in this context.

Comment: Also use `Long` rather than `Integer`.

Comment: @SLR I do appreciate what you are saying, but believe me, that is the only way that I get something...
Using your updated code below 'Sub x()' doesn't give me an error. Doesn't give me nothing at all, actually. All blanks... At least there is no error...

Comment: I appreciate the effort.

Comment: It's definitely copying? You get the "marching ants"? Do you have formulae in the source cells?

Comment: No, but if it makes any difference it is derived w the 'For' loop from **Chunk 1**, which is actually the same as the loop that doesn't work for the col count.

Comment: I suppose "marching ants" refers to the piling of the 'MS' ws in A1 of the 'HDaER' ws?

Comment: I think you need to post the rest as a new question. Keep each question as specific as possible. The code I posted above is supposed to be self-contained so that it doesn't need anything else in order for testing. Read [mcve].

Comment: Pff! You the man! Love it when someone refers useful literature on a specific issue.

Comment: Practically, I posted the whole code I have so far. The 3 chunks above. **Chunk 1** and **Chunk 3** work fine, but I can't wrap my head around the **Chunk 2** issue.